# Windows 10 change partition to be booted

Tags: windows-10, boot, efi, bootmgr

I bought a new bigger drive and I want to transfer Windows OS to it.

I have already cloned EFI partition to new drive and it works, but starts the system on old drive. Windows partition is cloned to new drive, too.

How to tell EFI to boot partition with system on new drive instead of old one?

Comment: Depending on the make/model , the choice of boot drive can usually be changed by pressing a button F2,F5,F10,Del, etc during bootup.

Comment: Older Thinkpads have a dedicated blue button for alternate boot options; newer Thinkpads throw a prompt on the screen to tell you to press [Enter] for alternate boot choices.

Comment: @K7AAY and Christopher I think you misunderstood the question. The OP is already booting from the new drive with the cloned ESP. OP *complains* that even so the system that boots [from the cloned ESP] is the system in the old drive and they want to know how to reconfigure the system to use the newly cloned Windows in the new drive.